# How wo fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone, pytz

I am getting an issue while attaching 'Europe/London' timezone to the variable time (05:30), I am able to attach utc timezone, is there a way where I can attach UK timezone ?

```
import sys
import os
import datetime
import boto3
import pytz
import time


ST = "05:30"

def test():
  WST1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(ST, '%H:%M').time()
  print(WST1)
  print(WST1.tzinfo)
  ST1 = pytz.utc.localize(WST1)
  print(ST1.tzinfo)
  # ST1 = timezone.localize(WST1)
  print(ST1)
  tz1 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
  T1 = tz1.localize(WST1)
  T1 = ST1.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz1)
  print(T1)



test()
```

Comment: It looks like `localize` is expecting a `datetime` not a `time`. If you remove `.time()` from the first line of the function it works. Whether that does what you want I can't say.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? The error clearly tells you that you cannot do timedelta arithmetic with datetime.time objects. You need to use datetime.datetime. Besides, working with time only also makes not a lot of sense in the context of time zones - without a date, their properties are pretty much undefined.

Comment: @Kemp if I remove ```.time()```, it will add adate as 1990-01-01 which I do not want

Comment: @MrFuppes - I have a variable ST = 05:30 and I am just trying to attach UK timezone to it.

Comment: so, which date do you want to use?

Comment: @MrFuppes Not looking for any date to use

Comment: please see my comment above: e.g. *5:30 am* might be UTC+1 or UTC+0 in time zone "Europe/London", depending on the date. So if you want to work with time zones, you must add a date since their UTC offsets change over time.